# Piranha CMS middleware to capture requests to /uploads

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, piranha-cms

When a request is made for an image|file it doesn't reach my middleware.

I can see that when `UseCms` is called it adds `PiranhaStartupFilter`

```
serviceBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, PiranhaStartupFilter>();
```

Which adds `UseStaticFiles()` to the ApplicationBuilder.

```
public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
{
    return builder =>
    {
        builder
            .UseSecurityMiddleware()
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseMiddleware<RoutingMiddleware>()
            .UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>();
        next(builder);
    };
}
```

How could I overwrite this functionality so that my middleware is called for requests?

I'm expecting a call to `/uploads/foo.jpg` would be picked up in the `InvokeAsync` method of my middleware, registered like so:

```
app.UsePiranha(options =>
{
    options.Builder.CustomImageTools();
});
```

At present only files & favicon requests reach the InvokeAsync method in my middleware.

Comment: If you want to modify the middleware for your application, why you don't directly put this middleware directly inside the programe.cs like this `app.UseMiddleware<UploadsMiddleware>();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As middleware in asp.net is executed in the order they are added into the pipeline it should be sufficient to add your interceptor before making any calls to Piranha.

You can add the middleware by adding a service above the call to `UseCms()` in `startup.cs`.

```
services.AddPiranha(options =>
{
    options.CustomImageFilter();
    options.UseCms();
}

public class CustomImageFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return app =>
        {
            app.UseWhen(
                context => some_condition,
                appbuilder => appbuilder.CustomImageTools()
            );
            // Call the next configure method
            next(app);
        };
    }
}
```